# Save pictures into different folder

Tags: android, android-camera

I have this code for take picture from my app, then save into different directory than default:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    directory_path = "/tempCamera";
    directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            directory_path);
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs();

    }

    camera_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
    camera_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent camera_intent = new Intent(
                    MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);

            camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(directory));
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(camera_intent, 0);

        }

    });
}
```

but pictures is always saved into default directory. What's wrong?

Comment: Change this `directory_path = "/tempCamera";` to sometring else, i.e.: `directory_path = "/YourAppName";`

Answer (score 3):

You should pass to the MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, not a path to folder, but a  path to a result image.

Comment: ok, so then in onActivityResult i obtain that path and i move image to my custom folder?